# how can i solve this error ( Field 'total_price' expected a number but got {'price__sum': 222} ) django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

how can i get the total_price of books which the added by user in store. i also add a `@property` to calculate and save the total price. when i try to save the form i getting typeError `Exception Value:  Field 'total_price' expected a number but got {'price__sum': 222}.`

how can i solve this issue?

Store

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Store(models.Model):
    keeper = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def save(self):
        self.total_price = self.books.all().aggregate(Sum('price'))
        super(Store, self).save()
```

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate returns dictionary so

```
   if self.pk:
        self.total_price = self.books.all().aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
```

also save method does not need @`property` decorator

---

EDIT:

It is Many to Many relationship which means better idea would keep track of [`m2m_changed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) signal with `post_clear` and change `total_price` also you can see this would be tedious job as you would still need to check if book changed price by overriding Book model save() method

---

I wouldn't suggest you to have total_price field as you can always [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/) this count in query, leave job to database as it is made for this kind of tasks

Comment: now this alert `"<Store: Store object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`